# Bootstrap tooltip for dynamically created element coming on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am dynamically adding an image to a span with below jQuery.

I want to show bootstrap tooltip on image's mouse enter, tooltip coming but from second time.

```
   $('span').append('<img src="Edited-Message.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" class="EditedChat" title="Removed />');
```

I am using following jQuery to add tooltip :-

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", "img.EditedChat", function () {
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Bind on the image to reposition the tooltip when it has finished loading :

```
$(img).load(function(){ $element.tooltipster('reposition') })
```

Comment: where should I write this line on document.ready? or before $("body").on("mouseenter", "img.EditedChat", function () {